# How do I get `annotate_models` gem to work with yard in markdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation-generation, annotate, yard

How do I get `annotate_models` gem to work with yard in markdown?

At the moment, I specify `--markup markdown` in `.yardopts` and use the following in `auto_annotate_models.rake`:

```
'format_markdown'         => 'true'
```

However, the markdown renders very weirdly. Here's how the file looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate generates markdown compatible with `kramdown`, hence specifying `--markup markdown --markup-provider kramdown` in `.yardopts` fixes this.

Here's the fixed render:

[image]